# Unfiling a document code from IBM knowledge center

Tags: java, filenet-p8, filenet-content-engine, containment

Is this still the only way or most efficient way to unfile a document from filenet?

```
static PropertyFilter pf = new PropertyFilter(); 

pf.addIncludeProperty(new FilterElement(null, null, null, "Containers", 
null));
// Get document to be unfiled.
Document doc = Factory.Document.fetchInstance(os, new Id("{8854236F-02D6- 40AB-B4B2-59B6756154D8}"), pf);

// Iterate all folders that contain the document, until the desired 
folder is found.
ReferentialContainmentRelationshipSet rcrs = doc.get_Containers();
Iterator iter = rcrs.iterator();
while (iter.hasNext() )
{
   ReferentialContainmentRelationship rcr = 
(ReferentialContainmentRelationship)iter.next();
   Folder folder = (Folder)rcr.get_Tail();
   if (folder.get_Id().equals(new Id("{C40106FE-B510-4222-BB42- 6D2FD5D21123}")))
   {
      rcr.delete();
      rcr.save(RefreshMode.REFRESH);
      break;
   }
}
```

This code performs what it supposed to do, but sometimes it would take up to 4 hours to unfile one document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfiling an object from a folder requires just one thing: deleting the corresponding `ReferentialContainmentRelationship` object. The latter can be obtained in several ways, but assuming you know the folder you want to unfile from, the most straighforward way is to use the [`unfile`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSNW2F_5.5.0/com.ibm.p8.ce.dev.java.doc/com/filenet/api/core/Folder.html?view=kc#unfile(com.filenet.api.core.IndependentlyPersistableObject)) method on `Folder`:

```
ReferentialContainmentRelationship rcr = folder.unfile(document);
rcr.save(RefreshMode.NO_REFRESH);
```

The code that you posted seems to be an adaptation of something designated for more generic task. I don't believe the documentation advises to unfile from a single folder in this way. Anyway, unless the document you are unfiling is filed into many thousands of folders, even with that unnecessary complication it is a matter of seconds to unfile it, not hours. There might be something wrong with your system.